# Initialize PostgreSQL in Docker

Tags: c#, postgresql, docker

I have an application that populates the database at startup. if I run the application with **docker-compose up**, everything is fine, but if I want to run each single images manually I cannot populate the database, I get a long list of exceptions.  This is a part of:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
  Entity Framework Core 2.0.1-rtm-125 initialized 'ConfigurationDbContext' 
using provider 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL' with options: 
MigrationsAssembly=Entities
Application startup exception: 
System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException 
(0x00000001): Resource temporarily unavailable
at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean 
includeIPv6)
at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Connect(NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<RawOpen>d__139.MoveNext()
```

This is part of my docker-compose.yml:

```
postgres:
  image: postgres
  environment:
    POSTGRES_USER: xxxx
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "xxxx"

  ports:
    - "8001:5432" 
  restart: always
  networks: 
  - my-network
```

Comment: What command are you using to "run each single images manually"?

Comment: docker run -d -p xxxx:xx image_name

Comment: I think you could be missing environment parameters. Try with `-e POSTGRES_USER=xxxx` and so on...